# could we convert a video file to all of this formats (swf,3gp,mp4, flv,ogv)?

Tags: asp.net, video, converters

consider user1 uploads a swf file,
user2 uploads a flv,
user 3 uploads a mp4 file,
user 4 uploads a 3gp file,

and for showing cross browser we need have above file in this formats (swf,3gp,mp4,flv,ogv)
how can do it as soon as user uploads his/her file in **asp.net**

---

Thanks @Florestan06
I just test this code

```
    protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string AppPath = Request.PhysicalApplicationPath;
    //This is the path of your application
    string inputPath = AppPath + "ffmpeg\\" + "tizer.mp4";
    //Source Video Path
    string outputPath = AppPath + "outputFolder\\" + "myVideoOutput.flv";
    //Destination Video Path
    string fileargs = " -i \"" + inputPath + "\" \"" + outputPath + "\"";
    //Command Line
    System.Diagnostics.Process proc = new System.Diagnostics.Process();
    proc.StartInfo.FileName = AppPath + "ffmpeg\\ffmpeg.exe";
    //Path of FFMPEG
    proc.StartInfo.Arguments = fileargs;
    proc.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
    proc.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = false;
    proc.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = false;
    proc.Start();
}
```

It convert tizer.mp4 to flv but it's size in 0 bytes now. do you have any Idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest you install [ffmpeg](http://www.ffmpeg.org/download.html) on your server and then call [ffmpeg commands through .NET](http://forums.asp.net/t/1124171.aspx?How+to+Execute+FFMpeg). This way you can process the different transcoding of your input file to the desired outputs. This of course once the upload is complete.

Though I am not sure why you need to have both SWF and FLV - FLV should suffice for flash based environment? Have a look [here](https://superuser.com/questions/547022/how-to-convert-mp4-to-swf) for more information.

**EDIT**: *It convert tizer.mp4 to flv but it's size in 0 bytes now. do you have any Idea?*

First you need to learn the basics of ffmpeg for transcoding to the different outputs you are targeting. You can start [here](http://sonnati.wordpress.com/2011/08/08/ffmpeg-%E2%80%93-the-swiss-army-knife-of-internet-streaming-%E2%80%93-part-ii/) and go deeper with the [ffmpeg documentation](https://www.ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg.html). First make sure your command works in a terminal/command Prompt.

Once this is ok I would suggest you go verbose on the output of your .Net/ffmpeg script trying to catch/log any major steps of the process. I was only pointing at an example of how to execute and external program from .Net. I guess you can find other examples on Stackoverflow or the MSDN community if this one is not working as expected for you.

Having a 0 bytes output file either suggests your ffmpeg command is not valid or there is an issue with your script executing ffmpeg.